# Java SE OOP,Classes, Objects, Methods

Tags: java, oop

Hello everybody I need some help. I have to classes Day and Weather each class has its fields.
Class Day with its fields(Date, temperature and comments ). Class Weather with its fields (Season and comments). Here is the main problem: Find and show the following data:Average temperature, day with the maximum temperature, day with longest comment. So I have wrote the basic structure of both classes easily, but with logical constructions I m stacked please some 
advise or help how to solve it or improve it I'm new in programming.
Here is the class Day:

```
public class Day {
    private Date date;
    private int temperature;
    private ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>() ;
    Weather weather;

    Day( Date date, int temperature, String comment){
        this.date=date;
        this.temperature=temperature;
        this.comments.add(comment);
    }
    public Date getDate(){
        return  date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date){
        this.date=date;
    }
    public int getTemperature(){
        return  temperature;

    }
    public  void setTemperature(int temperature){
        this.temperature=temperature;

    }
    public ArrayList<String> getComments() {
        return comments;

    }
    public void addComment(String comment){
        this.comments.add(comment);
    }
    public String longestComment() {
        int length = 0;
        String longestComment = "";
        for ( String comment : comments )
        {
            if ( comment.length() > length )
            {
                length = comment.length();
                longestComment = comment;
            }
        }
        return longestComment;
    }


    public  static  void main (String args []){
        Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();

        Day day=new Day(c.getTime(),20,"Today is normal temperature");
        day.addComment("Tomorrow is going to be the highest degree for ever in this summer");
        day.addComment("Yesterday was the coldest temperature");
        day.addComment("Next week is going to be the coldest temperature ever");
        day.addComment("In the early years of the ice era there was only highest degree of temperature for ever");
        System.out.println("the longest comment is:");
        System.out.println( day.longestComment() );
    }
}
```

and here the class Weather:

```
public class Weather {
private  String season;
    private String comments;
        Day [] day;

     public   Weather(String season, String comments, Day [] day){
         this.comments=comments;
         this.season=season;
         this.day=day;
       }

   public static void main (String args []){


   }
    public String getSeason(String season){
        return season;
    }
    public void setSeason(String season){
                    this.season=season;
    }
    public String getComments(String comments){
        return comments;
    }
          public void setComments(String comments){
              this.comments=comments;
          }
    public Day getDay(Day  day){
        return day ;
    }
    public void setDay(Day [] day){
        this.day=day;
    }
    public int averageTemp(int aver){
    for(int t=0; t<day.length;t++){
        if (aver==((day.length)/2)){

          return day[t].getTemperature();
    }
    }
        return 0;
    }
  public void maxTemp(){
      int max=0;

      for (int i=0; i<day.length;i++){

      }

  }
    public void findLongestComment(String comment){

   System.out.println("Comment\""+comment+"\":");
}
```

and which kind of type would you declare the Date?
please some explaination because this is the logical part of my application it 
influences for future developing of application
Thanks for everybody patient and understanding

Comment: Date is declared using java.util.Date or Calendar in java

Comment: Decide id day is a single Day, or an array of Day instances. If the latter, name the variable `days`, and not `day`, since an array contains several elements. You should also revisit your notion of an average.

Comment: using java.util.Calendar

Comment: my  question is how can I write the logical part in order to Find and show the following data:Average temperature, day with the maximum temperature

Answer (score 0):

Average temperature should probably be something more like:

```
public int averageTemp()
{
  int totalTemp=0;
  for (Day day1 : day)
  {
    totalTemp+=day1.getTemperature;
  }
  return totalTemp/day.length;
}
```

For max temp, you've got the right idea in what you did for longest comment. Just use the same logic: loop through all the entries, compare each to the highest found so far, if this one is higher, this becomes the highest so far.

Comment: how can i print this block in main method?

Comment: System.out.println("Average temp="+averageTemp); Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: No I wanted to give object  reference in main method like this:public static void main (String args []){

        Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();

        Weather weather=new Weather("Summer","very hot season");

        weather.addTemp(49);
        weather.addTemp(42);
        weather.addTemp(45);
        weather.addTemp(46);
        System.out.println(weather.averageTemp());
           System.out.println(c.getTime());
         System.out.println(weather.maxTemp());
            
    }
}

Comment: Okay, that looks good. Do you have a problem with what you put in that comment?

Comment: Jay can u please help me how to solve this problem  entirely?

Comment: What's your remaining problem?

Comment: please see my problem here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867079/i-m-stacked-with-oop-in-java

Comment: Jay really i m stacked i did part of them correctly in the middle i m stacked if i won't do it then it ll be bad because it occurs for further steps  thanks for helping and understanding